# Microsoft LUIS Multi-language support

Tags: chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Can we have multi-language support in Microsoft LUIS?
If yes, how can we implement it? If single agent works fine for it or do we need to create different data-sets for different languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Multilanguage chat application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-supported-languages#multi-language-luis-apps) with separate LUIS apps for each culture.
In order to have single LUIS application, you could use the [Translator Text API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/) to translate all incoming messages before they're sent to LUIS. In this case you'll want to use middleware to handle the translation before your LUIS Recognizer is called. You can also use middleware to translate your bot's response so you don't have to use additional localization inside of your bot

[Tokenizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-supported-languages#tokenization) in LUIS is different for each language in LUIS.

Here is one more [sample](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ChooseLanguageBot) where you can select a language from the bot and continue the consversation as required.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I think 2nd case of translating text into particular language is not good as it will fail in many cases and also will be complex when we add more datasets.

Comment: Yes, that is secondary option. Always creating an individual app for each language is the best approach.

Comment: But 1st option too has disadvantage that I cannot implement one single agent/app which can communicate in different language.
I've checked and found that Dialogflow solved this issue. In Dialogflow we can have multiple language for single agent. While calling that agent you just need to pass language in lang parameter.